# Need to find peak usage of each API call from Azure App Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, kql, azure-monitoring

Need to find each API Max hour usage in a given day in Azure App insight using query.
For example

API A has total hit between 1 PM to 2PM is 10, 2 PM to 3 PM is 20  and 3 PM to 4 PM is 15

API B has total hit between 1 PM to 2PM is 5,  2 PM to 3 PM  is 8  and 3 PM to 4 PM is 10

API C has total hit between 1 PM to 2PM is 30, 2 PM to 3 PM  is 12 and 3 PM to 4 PM is 9

Need result like this. Don't want which hour its hitting max , even with which hour is also fine .

| operation_Name | MaxRequestcount |
| --- | --- |
| API A | 20 |
| API B | 10 |
| API C | 30 |

```
requests
| summarize MaxRequestsCount=max(itemCount) by bin(timestamp, 1h) ,operation_Name 
| order by RequestsCount desc // order from highest to lower (descending)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, this should work:

```
let day_start = startofday(now()); // adjust as necessary
requests
| where timestamp between(day_start .. 1d)
| summarize HourlyRequestCount = sum(itemCount) by bin(timestamp, 1h), operation_Name 
| summarize MaxRequestsCount = max(HourlyRequestCount) by operation_Name
```

Comment: Removed my answer as I misunderstood, so I think you're right :)

Comment: Need a small change 
requests
| summarize MaxHourlyRequestCount = sum(itemCount) by bin(timestamp, 1h), operation_Name 
| summarize MaxRequestsCount = max(MaxHourlyRequestCount) by operation_Name

Answer (score 0):

```
requests
| summarize MaxHourlyRequestCount = sum(itemCount) by bin(timestamp, 1h), operation_Name 
| summarize MaxRequestsCount = max(MaxHourlyRequestCount) by operation_Name
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?